# Define $f(x)$ is integrable and $g(x)=\int_0^{\int_0^xf(n)dn}f(y)dy$, Prove $g'(0)=f(0)^2$

Tags: real-analysis

Here is the question:
Let $f(x)$ be an integrable function on $[-1,1]$. $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$. Define $g(x)=\int_0^{\int_0^xf(n)dn}f(y)dy$ and prove $g'(0)=f(0)^2$.

My initial thought was to look at $g(0)$ and say when you take an integral from $a$ to $b$ and $a=b$ then the integral is $0$, but I do not know how to show $f(0)^2=0$ from that point.

My next thought was that I will need to use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus II. Here is the definition from the book I am studying from:

Let $f$ be an integrable function on $[a,b]$. For x in $[a,b]$, let $F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$. Then $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ in $(a,b)$, then $F$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $F'(x_0)=f(x_0)$.

My work using this Theorem:

Let $h(x)=\int_0^xf(n)dn$. Since $f$ is integrable on $[-1,1]$, for $x$ in $[-1,1]$ we have that $h(x)$ is continuous. Since $f$ is continuous at $x=0$, then $h$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and $h'(0)=f(0)$.

Now relating $g$ to $h$, we know $g(x)=\int_0^{h(x)}f(y)dy$. This looks very similar to $h$, so we can say $g(x)=h(h(x))$. Then $g'(0)=h'(h(0))=f(h(0))=f(0)$, since $h(0)=0$ by definition of an integral with parameters that are equal. Now from here, we have $g'(0)=f(0)$, but I need to show $g'(0)=f(0)^2$. This is only true if they are both equal to either $0$ or $1$ I believe, but I am not sure how to do this or if I am even going in the right direction for this proof.

If anyone can tell me if I amm onto something or if I am way off base it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would do. Let
$$h(x) = \int_0^x f(n)\ dn $$

then we immediately have $h'(x) = f(x)$ by the FTOC, and $h(0) = 0$

By definition
$$ g(x) = \int_0^{h(x)} f(y)\ dy $$

Using the FTOC again we have
$$ g'(x) = f\big(h(x)\big)\cdot h'(x) = f\big(h(x)\big) \cdot f(x) $$

Therefore
$$ g'(0) = f\big(h(0)\big) \cdot f(0) = f(0)\cdot f(0) = \big(f(0)\big)^2 $$

**EDIT:** I read through your work more carefully. It's true that
$$ g(x) = h(h(x)) $$

However your derivative is incorrect
$$ g'(x) = h'\big(h(x)\big)\cdot h'(x) = f(h(x)) \cdot f(x) $$

As a consequence of the derivative chain rule. You can then proceed as above.

Comment: Of course! I forgot to use the chain rule when doing the derivative of $g(x)$. That solves the issue I had at the end, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

We have, using differentiation under the integral sign, $$g’(x)=[\int_{0}^{\int_{0}^{x} f(n)\, dn} f(y) \, dy]’=f(\int_{0}^{x} f(n) \, dn)[\int_{0}^{x} f(n) \, dn]’ = f(\int_{0}^{x}f(n) \, dn) [f(x)]$$

Thus, $$g’(0)=f(\int_{0}^{0} f(n)\, dn)[f(0)]=[f(0)][f(0)]=[f(0)]^2$$